# error with Uncrustify in xcode for an ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, code-formatting, uncrustify

I have installed the uncrustify through brew (as per the git instructions), and I have added the run script build phase to the xcode and tried to build an ios project, but the build is failing with the following error:

```
**/bin/sh: /Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testProj- amlbymrfycxuzmemclwtovltjxzl/Build/Intermediates/testProj.build/Debug-iphoneos/testProj.build/Script-AC898878187BE0A00056CAB1.sh: sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**
```

---

How can I resolve this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My sh script:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]
    then

    # recover directory to format :
    pathToSourcesDirectory=`echo $(pwd)/$1`

    # go to current folder :
    scriptDirectory=$(dirname $0)
    cd $scriptDirectory

    # find sources files to format :
    echo ""
    echo "==> Getting files to format in directory " + $pathToSourcesDirectory
    mkdir -p temp
    find $pathToSourcesDirectory -name "*.[mh]" > temp/sources_to_uncrustify.txt

    # format files :
    echo ""
    echo "==> Format files" 
    /usr/local/bin/uncrustify -F temp/sources_to_uncrustify.txt -c "../uncrustify_objective_c.cfg" --no-backup 

    # remove temp files : 
    rm -rf temp/

else 
    echo "Error : You must specify a source folder as first parameter"  

fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have *Shell* set to `/bin/sh` in the Xcode *Run Script* configuration:

[image]

(screenshot taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html)).

Comment: in the configuration i have added the file path  like this  sh CodeFormatter/scripts/formatOpenedSources.sh     and i have added CodeFormatter/scripts/formatOpenedSources.sh  file to the project

Comment: @RaviKiran Change `sh` to `/bin/sh`.